# Kingston HyperX 4GB and Bus compatibility

Tags: memory, ddr3

I'm considering purchasing Kingston HyperX 4GB . 
I believe it has 2000 Bus.and i have a gigabyte G41M-Combo which support DDR3 1333 .
Will that work?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the exact model/part number. There are lots o HyperX memories, with different speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which part number. If it's KHX2000C9AD3K3/3GX this then from the [datasheet](http://www.valueram.com/datasheets/KHX2000C9AD3K3_3GX.pdf) (linked to PDF):

> The SPDs are programmed to JEDEC standard
>   latency DDR3-1333MHz timing of 9-9-9 at 1.5V.

Translated: The memory *should* run fine, but the 2000MHz speeds are only under overclocked conditions.

Comment: I don't know exactly. I'm just considering upgrading my ram. Maybe I can rephrase the question to : If the RAM Bus speed is bigger than the motherboard's will it run?

Comment: It depends,the RAM modules are likely to sync with the bus speed, and slow down.

Comment: All the models?

Comment: Yep, as long as the RAM types match. If yo're adding the modules in adddition to your existing RAM modules - best to either remove the old modules or match the modules wrt speed and latencies. Unmatched RAM modules often result in stability problems and BSODs